# Multiple NoReverseMatch errors at password reset Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django project, still new at Django. I'm trying to follow instructions from this book but there are some changes in my project.

I'm trying to create login/registration with Django, but I'm stuck with reset password section. I know that my problem is related to name spacing but cannot figure out why is that and why isn't redirecting to pages mentioned in errors.

I have two errors:

Error 1:

```
NoReverseMatch at /password_reset/

Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Error 2:

```
NoReverseMatch at /reset/MQ/set-password/

Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found. 'password_reset_complete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

#### File *urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .feeds import LatestLessonsFeed
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'learning_app'

urlpatterns = [
    #lessons
    path('', views.lesson_list, name='lesson_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:lesson>/', views.lesson_detail, name='lesson_detail'),
    #tags
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.lesson_list, name='lesson_list_by_tag'),
    #feed
    path('feed/', LatestLessonsFeed(), name='post_feed'),

    # previous login view
    # path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    # login / logout urls
    #path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    #path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    # change password urls
    #path('password-change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    #path('password-change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
    # reset password urls
    #path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    #path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    #path('password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    #path('password-reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),

    #dashboard
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    #django auth
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

### HTML files:

#### File *login.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Log-in</h1>
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% else %}
    <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="login-form">
    <form action="{% url 'learning_app:login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
    <p>
      <a href="{% url 'learning_app:password_reset' %}">
        Forgotten your password?
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

#### File *password_reset_form.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Forgotten your password?</h1>
  <p>Enter your e-mail address to obtain a new password.</p>
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'learning_app:password_reset' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send e-mail"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

#### File *password_reset_email.html*

```
Someone asked for password reset for email {{ email }}. Follow the link below:
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url "learning_app:password_reset_confirm" uidb64=uid token=token %}
Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.get_username }}
```

#### File *password_reset_done.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Reset your password</h1>
  <p>We've emailed you instructions for setting your password.</p>
  <p>If you don't receive an email, please make sure you've entered the address you registered with.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

#### File *password_reset_confirm.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Reset your password{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Reset your password</h1>
  {% if validlink %}
    <p>Please enter your new password twice:</p>
    <form method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <p><input type="submit" value="Change my password" /></p>
    </form>
  {% else %}
    <p>The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Are there any obvious mistakes that I made?

Comment: `#path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done')` This line in `urls.py` would define that view, except it has been commented out.

Comment: it's managed with `path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`... but same happens if i remove comments on lines above. Problem is that I have added `app_name = 'learning_app'`, to add multiple apps, instructions are without app name.

Comment: Where, exactly, is the error?  Presumably you have view code or a template that is trying to access a url named `password_reset_done`, but I don't see any such code or template.

Comment: I don't know, that's it the issue. I kinda figured out that is because of app_name since you would usually get error with `NoReverseMatch`. It doesn't load template `password_reset_done.html`, but it does send this token from template in terminal `#path('password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),`.

Comment: Also tried some solutions from online, like using reverse_lazy: `path('password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="/registration/password_reset_confirm.html",success_url=reverse_lazy("password_reset_done"),post_reset_login=True),name='password_reset_confirm'),`. It still hasn't worked!

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` in settings.py, so the error page will print a full error message?

Comment: Yes, I do. I couldn't figure out, but you might: https://snipboard.io/wxPEVU.jpg

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77551467/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your auth urls are not in the learning_app but included. Meaning you cannot use learning_app namespace to reference them.

To fix the problem simply remove the learning_app: from your {% url %} tags in the templates. That should do the job. Hope this helps.

Example:

```
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
      <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
    </form>
```